# Issue running python script from crontab?

Tags: cron, python3

I have a script `/home/projects/temperature_logger/analyze.py` that does some work on a `temp.log` file, which is really a csv of a date and the current raspberry pi temperature.  This python script also logs the results to a `.log` file.  Calling it from the command line like `sudo python3 analyze.py` works as expected, but for some reason I cannot get it ot work with crontab.

I have run `sudo chmod +x analyze.py` as well as `sudo chmod ugo+w analyze.py`.

My `whereis python3` says `/usr/bin/python3`.  The shebang at the top of my `analyze.py` script is `#!/usr/bin/python3`.

My crontab script is
`* * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/projects/temperature_logger/analyze.py`

For testing purposes all I have actually running right now is

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.info("running file!")
```

in my analyze.py but I do not see this getting populated to my log file unless I manually call `sudo python3 analyze.py` from within the directory.

What am I doing wrong here?  The syslogs don't seem to indicate anything wrong but perhaps I don't understand them?  Apologies for the picture I am unsure how to copy from the PuTTy terminal [image]

Update:  I added all permissions for my user `ubuntu` with  `sudo chmod -R a+rwx /home/projects/temperature_logger`.  I then changed the crontab, cleared out my root cron and put the call to the python script under ubuntu's cron file.  I do see this reflected under the syslog now
[image]

It does not seem to indicate any error.  However, the script which when I call it with `python3 analyze.py` it does write properly to my `scripts.log` file, but when it's called from the cron, which it says is running the syslog - I don't see anything logged.

Solved:
So this was due to me misunderstanding waht the home directory for my user account was and what the current working directory of the script was.  In my `analyze.py` script I had `logging.basicConfig(filename='scripts.log', ...)`, which when I ran from the directory with `sudo`, wrote to `/home/projects/temperature_logger/scripts.log`, but when it was called from my user's cron file, it wrote to `/home/ubuntu/scripts.log`.

Comment: From PuTTy you can select and that goes into the clipboard. Then you just use Paste (Ctrl-V).

Comment: What user's crontab are you using. If the script requires root permissions to run, then use root's crontab.

Comment: Does the script really require root (full system) privileges just to process a CSV file?

Comment: Let me ask a different way, since I'm going to be flashing ubuntu 20.04 to my raspberry pis memory card shortly anyways and then pulling /home/projects/temperature_logger from my git repo.

Where would I want my project file?  I made up the directory /projects/ under home to start working on coding, but I don't know what the convention is and if thats affecting permissions at all.

And then, from who's cron would I want to be calling the `analyze.py`?

Comment: Help yourself by having a look at any `stderr` output generated. Do this by redirecting `stderr` to `stdout` (`2>&1`), to a separate file; e.g. `/usr/bin/python3 /home/projects/temperature_logger/analyze.py >> /home/myusernm/log.txt  2>&1`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you are writing scripts.log but for testing if you are using logging.info then make sure you have set the basis config correct for logging... like so...

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(filename='test.log',level=logging.DEBUG)
    logging.info("running file!")
```